# Assigning rows to variables using MySQLi and PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm just starting to dab into MySQLi after using MySQL for a while. I found this little code snippet on a tutorial, and just had a question about it (since Google won't return any results for me on this...).

```
<?php 

$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "user", "password", "world"); 

if (!$link)
{
    $error = mysqli_connect_error();
    $errno = mysqli_connect_errno();
    print "$errno: $error\n";
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT Name, Population, Continent FROM Country WHERE Continent=? ORDER BY Name LIMIT 1";

$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($link);
if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $query))
{
    print "Failed to prepare statement\n";
}
else
{
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $continent);

    $continent_array = array('Europe','Africa','Asia','North America');

    foreach($continent_array as $continent)
    {
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM))
        {
            foreach ($row as $r)
            {
                print "$r ";
            }
            print "\n";
        }
    }
}
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Courtesy of http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php

If I'm understanding this correctly then `$r` will now do an array of all of the results found in all of the rows called. How can I assign a variable to each row? Can I still do something similar like I did in MySQL?

```
$username = $row['username'];
```

Or is there something completely different now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for example;
we have Name, Population, Continent columns that we are selecting.

```
Name | Population | Continent
X    |  1         |  A
Y    |  2         |  B
Z    |  3         |  C
```

and these are the rows returned as result of this query..

in first iteration, you will get `$row` like this

```
array("Name"=> "X", "Population"=>"1", "Continent"=>"A");
```

and in second iteration, you will get `$row` like this

```
array("Name"=> "Y", "Population"=>"2", "Continent"=>"B");
```

and so on.
so, you can use it as you mentioned(like `$row["Name"]`)

Comment: I'm trying to test it now, but I can't figure out how to get it working with the $link variable since I just include config.php instead of having it connect in that file. Ugh, I wish mysql wasn't deprecated.

Comment: where are you having trouble?
and what is inside your config.php?

Comment: My config.php just has `mysqli_connect("localhost", "mike_market", "passwordremoved", "mike_market");` in it. That should work, right? But then in the script above if I remove the connect, then `$link` no longer does anything.

Comment: The simple way of doing this is to define constants in your config file,, like `define("DB_HOST_NAME", "localhost");` `define("DB_USERNAME", "username");` `define("DB_PASSWORD", "password");` `define("DB_NAME", "my_database");` and then in your main file.. do this `$link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST_NAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);`

Comment: Why wouldn't I want it connected all the time by just connecting the way it is now and including that at the top of every file? What's different now?

Comment: yes, you can do that also.. the purpose is, you have to keep `$link` with you

Comment: Is there any way around that though? I just want to run a select query, and set the rows as variables, then display those variables. I don't want the connect script in the same file for every single file...

Comment: for writing connect script only once, make a config file and put this code in it.
`<?php $link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "user", "password", "world"); ?>` and include it in every file. and keep the code as it is.

Comment: and why do you want to save rows as variables? where do you want to use it?

Comment: I'd like to use it to check if it matches user input (for a log in script). I'm just not very familiar with arrays.

Comment: then it is the time to get familiar with arrays.

Comment: for login purpose, you can use `WHERE` clause in sql

Comment: Thanks, gonna take a quick look at some tutorials on arrays.

Answer (score 3):

Within that `while` loop, you can use the variable `$row` and it will represent the contents of the current row.  So, you can create an array before the loop and assign each row to a new index in the array within that loop.  Once the loop is done executing, your array will be populated.

```
$arrayVar = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM))
{
  $arrayVar[] = $row[];
}
```

Comment: I have added an example =)